# How do I pass multiple arguments through an R function to ggplot, both aesthetics and scale format?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

## How do I pass multiple arguments through to my ggplot function?

Here is an example of the plot I want to automate.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut, y=price) ) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar)
p
```

[image]

But I want to graph multiple different variables and use the appropriate scale e.g. price, depth etc, some are in dollars.

So I made a function

```r
myfunction <- function(var1,var2){
  p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut, y= var1) ) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = var2)
  p
  return(p)
}
```

When I test the function, it doesn't work. Both arguments cause different errors on their own.

```r
myfunction("price","dollar")
```

For var1 I get:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

and var2:

```
Error in f(..., self = self) : Breaks and labels are different lengths
```

- **Question 1. Why doesn't that work? This is the most important question for me.**

I then wish to make multiple graphs, which I can do with a for loop, but I keep hearing I should do it with apply. Here's what I tried.

- **Question 2. How would you make the multiple graphs work with `apply?`**

```r
FirstPlotData <- c("price","dollar")
SecondPlotData <- c("depth", "comma")
plotMetaData <- data.frame(FirstPlotData,SecondPlotData)
```

- `lapply` doesn't work for me with multiple arguments. Can it pass multiple arguments?

```
lapply(plotMetaData, function(avar,bvar)myfunction(avar, bvar))
```

- Would `mapply` work? How?

```
mapply(mytestfunction,plotMetaData[1,],plotMetaDataList[2,])
```

Thanks in advance. I note that I could do the multiple graphs with facet, but for my more complex example, with hiding outliers, scaling, and also doing stats, then doing the multiple plots and putting in a `{cowplot}` grid seems easier.

Comment: can you provide a sample of output?

Comment: Figure and error output added.

Comment: Look up (and google) the function aes_string().

Comment: Thank Joran, that would have fixed the first problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(rlang) # for sym

myfunction <- function(var1,var2){
  p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut, y= !! sym(var1)) ) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = get(var2))
  p
  return(p)
}
myfunction('price','dollar')
```

Comment: Thanks. In a perfect world the same syntax would solve both problems?

Comment: I think you may want to have a recent version of ggplot2 installed - there have been some updates to evaluation (I think) and the code works with 3.0.0+, but not the very old version I had installed previously, but noting i used aes_string() from below with get() from this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `aes_string`. This function has been designed to make programming with ggplot easier (similar ideas have also been applied to `dplyr` commands). The following works:

```
library(tidyverse)

data(diamonds)

myfunction <- function(var1){
  p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes_string(x="cut", y= var1) ) + 
    geom_boxplot()
  p
  return(p)
}

myfunction("price")
```

## Why?

contrast the following:

```
# works
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut, y= price) ) + geom_boxplot()

# these 2 are equivalent, but do not work
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut, y= "price") ) + geom_boxplot()
var1 = "price"
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut, y= var1) ) + geom_boxplot()

# these 2 are equivalent, both works but inputs are strings
ggplot(diamonds, aes_string(x="cut", y= "price") ) + geom_boxplot()
var1 = "price"
ggplot(diamonds, aes_string(x="cut", y= var1) ) + geom_boxplot()
```

## Using apply?

For this purpose I would be inclined to use loops (others are welcome to disagree). If you are set on using an apply approach then you probably want `apply` as `lapply`, `mapply`, `vapply` and `sapply` are list-, multivariate-, vector- and simple-apply respectively.

Comment: aes_string solves the aes part, but the other answer sorts the scale as well. For loop seems easier to me too.

Answer (score 1):

A more `ggplot` way of doing this now, is using `.data` pronoun.

```r
library(ggplot2)

myfunction <- function(var1, var2) {
  p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = .data[[var1]])) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    scale_y_continuous(
      labels = getFromNamespace(x = var2, ns = "scales")
    )
  p
  return(p)
}

myfunction("price", "dollar")
myfunction("price", "comma")
```

Then to create multiple plots with these function by passing multiple arguments, a better and **tidier** approach is using `map` functions from the `{purrr}`

```r
plots <- purrr::map2(
  .x = c("price", "price"),
  .y = c("dollar", "comma"),
  .f = myfunction
    )
```

So, `plots[[1]]` contains the 1st plot with `var1 = "price"` and `var2 = "dollar"` and `plots[[2]]` contains the 2nd plot with `var1 = "price"` and `var2 = "comma"`.